# How to assign a unique uniform to different tiles that uses the same type of shaders

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm creating this tile-game, and each tile reuses the same shader, but in order to make each tile unique I'm passing a uniform value into the tile based on its positions.

I've added the rough illustration below;
[image]

this is my fragment shaders

```
#ifdef GL_ES                                
precision lowp float;                       
#endif                                      

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;               
varying vec2 v_texCoord;                    

uniform sampler2D CC_Texture0;              
uniform float delta;                        
uniform vec2 resolution;                    
uniform vec2 position;                      

uniform vec2 modulesize;                    
uniform vec2 moduleoffset;                  

void main()                                 
{                                           

    // just a test
    if(moduleoffset.x > 100.0) {

        // this never gets called
        gl_FragColor    = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor    = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
    }

};
```

This is how I assign the uniform, these methods are being called after everything has been built.

```
getShaderProgram()->use();

_shader->setUniformLocationWith2f(_shader->getUniformLocationForName("moduleoffset"), this->getPosition().x, this->getPosition().y);


_shader->setUniformLocationWith2f(_shader->getUniformLocationForName("modulesize"), _moduleSize.width, _moduleSize.height);
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but I'm not sure why at the if else statement, moduleoffset.x > 100.0 never gets called/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using OpenGL ES, the lowp precision qualifier means that the variable will only be able to store numbers between -2.0f and 2.0f. See [precision qualifiers](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf). Change it to highp and hopefully that fixes your problem.

Comment: Hm, ok first how about changing your shader so you pass the uniform variable straight into the output colour. That way you can confirm that your uniform setting is working. I.e void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(moduleoffset, 0.0, 1.0); } ... setUniformLocationWith2f(..., 0.0f, 1.0f) should produce green.

Comment: I tried that it worked. But I assumed the error came because of cocos2d-x, I'm changing the whole framework now

Comment: Ok let me know if you run into any other problems :)